# SQLite Trigger syntax error at end of any query

Tags: android, sqlite, triggers

I'm using Android's SQLite

My schema:

```
CREATE TABLE timecards (
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 template_id INTEGER,
 autofill_id INTEGER,
 employee_name TEXT,
 production_name TEXT,
 week_ending TEXT,
 FOREIGN KEY(template_id) REFERENCES templates(id),
 FOREIGN KEY(autofill_id) REFERENCES autofills(id)
);

CREATE TABLE timecard_fields (
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 timecard_id INTEGER,
 timecard_field_name TEXT,
 timecard_field_value TEXT,
 FOREIGN KEY(timecard_id) REFERENCES timecards(id)
);

CREATE TABLE autofills (
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 template_id INTEGER,
 last_used TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE autofill_fields (
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 autofill_id INTEGER,
 autofill_field_name TEXT,
 autofill_field_value TEXT,
 FOREIGN KEY(autofill_id) REFERENCES autofills(id)
);

CREATE TABLE templates (
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 template_name TEXT
);
```

The trigger I'm trying to use:

```
CREATE TRIGGER timecard_employee_name_delete_trigger DELETE ON timecard_fields
WHEN OLD.timecard_field_name='employee_name'
BEGIN
    UPDATE timecards
         SET employee_name = (SELECT af.autofill_field_value FROM autofills af WHERE af.autofill_id = autofill_id AND af.autofill_field_name = 'employee_name')
         WHERE id=OLD.timecard_id;
END;
```

It is a complicated trigger, I know. The idea is to pull the value from another table. I'm not sure if it's correct, however, I get the same syntax error when I substitute this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER timecard_employee_name_delete_trigger DELETE ON timecard_fields
WHEN OLD.timecard_field_name='employee_name'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO templates (template_name) VALUES('name');
END;
```

This error always appears on the first query inside the trigger:

> (1) near ";": syntax error

The INSERT INTO query works fine outside of the trigger.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of `INSERT INTO templates (template_name) VALUES('name');` did you try `INSERT INTO templates (id, template_name) VALUES(null, 'name');`

Comment: Just tried: same error

Answer (score 0):

Turns out VIEWs were a better way to handle this anyway. Here's what I came up with:

```
CREATE VIEW timecard_info_view AS
SELECT DISTINCT timecards.id AS timecard_id,
templates.template_name AS template_name,
timecards.autofill_id AS autofill_id,
(SELECT CASE
  WHEN ((SELECT timecard_fields.timecard_field_value FROM timecard_fields
  WHERE timecard_fields.timecard_field_name='employee_name' AND timecard_fields.timecard_id=timecards.id) IS NOT NULL)
THEN
  (SELECT timecard_fields.timecard_field_value FROM timecard_fields
  WHERE timecard_fields.timecard_field_name='employee_name' AND timecard_fields.timecard_id=timecards.id)
ELSE
  (SELECT autofill_fields.autofill_field_value FROM autofill_fields
  WHERE autofill_fields.autofill_field_name='employee_name' AND autofill_fields.autofill_id=timecards.autofill_id)
END) AS employee_name,
(SELECT CASE
  WHEN ((SELECT timecard_fields.timecard_field_value FROM timecard_fields
  WHERE timecard_fields.timecard_field_name='picture' AND timecard_fields.timecard_id=timecards.id) IS NOT NULL)
THEN
  (SELECT timecard_fields.timecard_field_value FROM timecard_fields
  WHERE timecard_fields.timecard_field_name='picture' AND timecard_fields.timecard_id=timecards.id)
ELSE
  (SELECT autofill_fields.autofill_field_value FROM autofill_fields
  WHERE autofill_fields.autofill_field_name='picture' AND autofill_fields.autofill_id=timecards.autofill_id)
END) AS production_name,
(SELECT CASE
  WHEN ((SELECT timecard_fields.timecard_field_value FROM timecard_fields
  WHERE timecard_fields.timecard_field_name='week_ending' AND timecard_fields.timecard_id=timecards.id) IS NOT NULL)
THEN
  (SELECT timecard_fields.timecard_field_value FROM timecard_fields
  WHERE timecard_fields.timecard_field_name='week_ending' AND timecard_fields.timecard_id=timecards.id)
ELSE
  (SELECT autofill_fields.autofill_field_value FROM autofill_fields
  WHERE autofill_fields.autofill_field_name='week_ending' AND autofill_fields.autofill_id=timecards.autofill_id)
END) AS week_ending
FROM timecards
LEFT JOIN templates
ON timecards.template_id=templates.id
LEFT JOIN timecard_fields
ON timecard_fields.timecard_id=timecards.id
LEFT JOIN autofill_fields
ON timecards.autofill_id=autofill_fields.id
```